# Table of content: link at the page number instead of the section body

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref

I saw in some articles, the links in the table of content appear in the pages. For example, suppose the first section, Introduction, is at page 11 as the following:

`1 Introduction               11`

Then the box showing the link is at around number 11 (page number).

In my machine, however, when I use `\tableofcontents`, the box is around the section title, i.e. "Introduction".

What is the setting I'm missing here? Thanks.

Comment: Try `\usepackage[linktocpage=true]{hyperref}`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Hi, can you change your comment to an answer so that I can accept it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The standard setup of the package `hyperref` is to use the content titles (i.e. the section or chapter etc. names) in the `ToC` as link, however, the option `linktocpage=true` to `hyperref` or in `\hypersetup` will use the page number, saying `linktocpage` only will work as well (for the lazy ones ;-)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext} 
\usepackage[linktocpage]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{First}
\blindtext[5]
\section{Second}
\blindtext[10]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 23):

It is even possible to link **both**: The section label and the page number. Just pass `linktoc=all`.

```
\usepackage[linktoc=all]{hyperref}
```

### Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext} 
\usepackage[linktoc=all]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{First}
\blindtext[5]
\section{Second}
\blindtext[10]
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]

MWE is based on the MWE by Christian Hupfer.