# Changing only the number in table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, color, tocloft

My minimal document looks like this

[image]

This colors the numbers in the table of contents, and in the section. How can i color the page number in the table of contents as well?

I tried using `tocloft` and to redefine `\cftXpagefont` as it said in the manual, alas this did not change anything. I do not have to use `tocloft` any package that can solve my problem is more than welcome.

## Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color,tocloft}
\newcommand{\cftXpagefont}{\color{red}}

\renewcommand\thesection{\textcolor{red}{\arabic{section}}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{a} \newpage \section{b} \newpage \section{c}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no `\cftXpagefont` defined. Instead, the `X` refers to the section type in question, like `chap` (for `\chapter`), `sec` (for `\section`), `subsec` (for `\subsection`), *etc.* So, you can redefine `\cftsecpagefont`, like below.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor,tocloft}

\renewcommand{\cftsecpagefont}{\bfseries\color{red}}

\renewcommand\thesection{\textcolor{red}{\arabic{section}}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{a} \newpage \section{b} \newpage \section{c}

\end{document}
```

<sub>Note that a redefinition of `\thesection` will also affect references. If you don't want that you'd have to adjust the formatting in two locations (when setting the sectional title and what it written to the ToC or updated `\cftsecpresnum`).</sub>

Comment: Actually I need to have this work with refferences, In particular `hyperref`. I was able to get the correct output using `\renewcommand{\cftsecpagefont}{\color{red}\hypersetup{linkcolor=red}}
\renewcommand{\cftsecaftersnum}{\hypersetup{linkcolor=black}}`. Is this ok, or is there a better solution?
`

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar: By default the page is not linked. You'll have to use the option `linktocpage` to make it work (see [Table of content: link at the page number instead of the section body](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/238430/5764)). This will switch the linking from the titles to the page number.